# error when making connection in oracle with new user

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Status : Failure -Test failed: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
this error is showing when making a connection with a newly created user in oracle sql developer but when connecting to system it is connecting normally

Comment: Three options- 1) you didn't actually create a database user (what exactly did you do to create the user), 2) the username and/ or password is incorrect, 3) you're not connecting to the database where you created the database user.  Unfortunately, its hard from here to guess which is more likely.

Comment: i enterd sql developer as sys and then i go to users then right click add user then i gave this user the previlages thats it

Comment: Make sure you don't have AS SYSDBA enabled on your new user connection like you do for sys